# jQuery doesnt work with AngularJS ng-route view

Tags: angularjs

I have four html pages that I want to inject in my index.html using AngularJS ngRoute.

I have a carousel on hairstyle.html and a photo zoom-in jquery on salon.html, both do not work on angularjs route.

How do I make my jquery code work on AngularJS ngRoute view?

Here is the link to my codes: https://embed.plnkr.co/wyoVtQ/